# Is it possible to use DC-restoration as a half-wave rectifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, dc, rectifier

A simple DC-retoration circuit: [image]

[image]

seems to do the about the same job as a half-wave rectifier, is it standard to use these two circuit instead of each other ?

I tried to increase the capacitance of the capacitor to make this circuit serve as a full-wave rectifier but so far my attempts led me to the exact same results as above, Is there anyway (change diode type ...) to make a full-wave rectifier of this circuit ?

Comment: That *is* a half-wave rectifier turned upside down (and with a very small capacitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capacitor value is too low to get good results with most diodes- the diode capacitance can be much larger than 10pF, especially with larger diodes.

This circuit is similar to the voltage doubler used in many older microwave ovens.

A mains-frequency transformer steps up the input voltage to a few thousand volts. A diode and capacitor gives you double the voltage for the negative half-cycles.

Full description and animated gif from [this](http://www.microtechfactoryservice.com/doubler.html) website. Don't pay too much attention to the arrow or the direction of the arrow, it's the opposite of conventional current flow through the magnetron.

[image]

Note that you do not get smooth DC out of this, you get pulses that are always positive (your circuit) or negative (the above circuit). That's fine for a microwave oven magnetron. It may not be fine for some other load.

So, yes, it's possible and the above application has been proven practical in hundreds of millions of microwave ovens.

Comment: +1 the microwave uses such a rectifier .I wonder what the input current waveform would look like ? would it be better than other approaches?

Comment: @Autistic Input current waveform should be capacitive (leading current). It allows the use of a lower voltage transformer so more economical and reliable. More recent higher end microwave ovens use [IGBT resonant inverter](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-5XQi-_PGrCY/UEnW1UzTtbI/AAAAAAAAAh4/nmHDUTYpAHg/s1600/4.bmp) technology with a doubler (2 *fast* high-voltage diodes + 2 caps) on the output but that was not practical until fairly recently.

Answer (score 0):

The Villard rectifier is a good example of using a DC restorer as a half wave rectifier .This is sometimes used for AGC generation in vintage AM  car radios .You could say that the CUK convertor uses this for its output stage .I have used the villard in pushpull as a fullwave rectifier .So the answer is YES .

Answer (score 0):

Yes   Old vacuum tube NTSC TVs used a tube diode to clamp (DC restore) on the sync tip.